# Can I convert a String into Integer or assign it with a value?

Tags: java, string, int, converters

I wanna ask if I can convert a `String` into an `int` or give the String a value.

Here is my Code: In my first line of the Method I generate a customer number for example "KU605-43", "CU629-34", "YT634-45".... as a String,

In the next line I take out my number for example of the first example 60543.

I try to `ParseInt` `ValueOf` and so on but it still does not work.

```
public int wertigkeitUeberpruefen(){
    String str = generate();
    str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
}
```

Comment: int number=Integer.parseInt(str); should work. otherwise there might be still characters in it which cannot be parsed. in this case you should print it out, because regex seems to be right

Comment: Thanks it works^^ fineally^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the following works, where `value` is the number.

```
public int wertigkeitUeberpruefen(){
     String str = generate();
     str = str.replaceAll("\\D","");
     int value = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First remove all non-numeric characters. Then parse the string to an integer and return it.

```
public int stringToParse(String str){
    str = str.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");
    return Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```